# Enable Pin Controll subsystem in kernel 4.14

Tags: linux, device-driver

I use and build a kernel 4.14 which is already running on a ARM processor.
Now I would include the MCP23S08 driver ([pinctrl-mcp23s08.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/pinctrl/pinctrl-mcp23s08.c?h=linux-4.14.y&id=c04fc6fa5c96ec57316527b2228fa31f26494abe))
For that, I use `make menuconfig` to enable the driver. Unfortunately, I could not find an entry for the *Pin Control* subsystem in which the driver should be.

For testing, I checked out the kernel 4.17 in which the entry *Device Driver->Pin Controlls* exist. According to the entry in [LKDD](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/PINCTRL.html) I think something changed in the configuration method between kernel 4.14 and 4.15.

Does someone now, how to activate the Pin Control subsystem in kernel 4.14? Thank you for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to enable the Pin control subsystem:

At least in that kernel version (4.14) the pin control subsystem is a machine configuration. I activated it in the */arch/arm/mach-*/Kconfig* file. After that, the entry was shown in the kernel menuconfig.

Comment: btw: The entry in the Kconfig file is: *select PINCTRL*